# Rename file based on size in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to rename a file that's greater than 5gb in an existing folder. When I run the script nothing happens, I'm not sure if the parameters or rename-item is incorrect. Help is greatly appreciated

```
$Path="C:\tmp\NPI_Archive"

Get-ChildItem $Path

$FileSizeLimit = ((5GB) -As [int])
$File = $Path -As [System.IO.FileInfo]
If ($File.Length -gt $FileSizeLimit)
{
    Rename-Item $Path "$($File.DirectoryName)\$($File.BaseName)"-NewName "$($File.DirectoryName)\$($File.BaseName)\NPI_Import.csv”
}
```

Comment: Is NPI_Archive the file or a folder?

Comment: [1] your `$File` variable DOES NOT have a file in it. instead, it has a directory. ///// [2] your `"$($File.DirectoryName)\$($File.BaseName)"` is adding a double `\\`in the directory name. the value comes back as `c:\\tmp` _if there is a real path there_. if there is no such path, then you get `c:\tmp`. ///// [3] directories don't have any value in the `.Length` property. you will always get a zero from that. ///// [4] your cast of `5gb` to an `[int]` will not work as that is too large for a standard int. you need `int64`.

Comment: If you're going to use the [`-As` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_type_operators) remember that you need to actually **test the result** for `$null` to see if the cast succeeded.  Typically, though, if you _know_ an object is (supposed to be) of a particular type you'd use the [cast operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#cast-operator--) (e.g. `$File = [System.IO.FileInfo] $Path`), which throws an error if the cast cannot be performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are renaming the item, you are adding a slash which is not allowed in file names. If you are trying to create another directory, please clarify. Additionally, I assumed there are multiple files in that directory, which would require being looped over, as Get-ChildItem can result in multiple objects. Let me know if this fixes it for you.

Edit: Fixed a typo as pointed out.

```
$Path="C:\tmp\NPI_Archive"
$File = Get-ChildItem $Path
$FileSizeLimit = 5kb
foreach($f in $File){
    If ($f.Length -gt $FileSizeLimit)
    {
        Rename-Item -path $f.FullName -NewName "$($f.BaseName)-NPI_Import.csv”
    } 
}
```

Comment: Your rename-item will not work because "$($file)" expands to only be the filename with no actual path. The above code works with this modified line. Rename-Item -path $File.FullName -NewName "$($file.BaseName)-NPI_Import.csv”

Comment: You are not using $F in the loop. change this foreach($F in $File){ to foreach($file in $File){

Comment: Sorry one more thing all of the $file needs to actually be $F in the loop and in the rename. You also don't actually need the "$()" around the file path portion but it works either way. (ah Harminder beat me to it).

Comment: Wow, I'm not sure how I overlooked that. Thank you both once again. I have applied the changes.

Answer (score 2):

For your `$FileSizeLimit` variable, you are trying to cast 5GB in bytes (5368709120) to an Int32 (max value of 2147483647). Since the value is too big to be an `Int32`, an `InvalidCastException` is thrown. Changing `int` to `long` or `Int64` should fix it.

```
$FileSizeLimit = ((5GB) -As [long])
```

Comment: To add to this, using `-As` instead of a straight cast was actually hiding the problem.  `5GB` cannot be cast to `[int]`, so `(5GB) -As [int]` returns `$null` with no error.  `[int] 5GB` fails explicitly, however, throwing an exception with message `Cannot convert value "5368709120" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Value was either too large or too small for an Int32."` that makes it obvious what the problem is.  Not only is `-As` unnecessary and obscure the problem in this case, casting at all is unnecessary; run `(5GB).GetType()` and you'll see `5GB` is an `[Int64]` in the first place.

Comment: There are several additional problems with the script besides the int casting. Please see my and others answers as well.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the wording of your question/script i'm assuming NPI_Archive is a folder in which case your check is against the folder.

```
$File = $Path -As [System.IO.FileInfo]
If ($File.Length -gt $FileSizeLimit)
```

Is going to result in it checking the size of "C:\tmp\NPI_Archive" which is nothing so it will not fire your if statement.

Your Rename-Item also has some errors which depending on if that's a folder or a file in the path statement the fix is different for.

```
Rename-Item -path $File.FullName -NewName "$($file.BaseName)-NPI_Import.csv”
```

Will fix it if its an actual file and is also the line you would want to use if you modify it to loop through all the files in a folder.

Edit -

You may have 3 issues as Jesse is also correct about the Int.